# Relational Database simple search string

Tags: mysql, search, relational-database

Hey guys,
This is a follow-up to a question that I asked earlier. It is my first time using a relational database and I need help with a quick search string to bring up desired results.

Background information: I'm making a database for my photo portfolio and want to be able to retrieve image links/data via their categories. Each image can be listed in multiple categories.

My database is set-up as follows :

TABLE `tbl_images` (`image_id`, `image_title`, `image_location`, `image_descrip`,`image_url`)

TABLE `tbl_categories` (`category_id`,`category_name`,`category_descrip`)

TABLE `tbl_image_categories` (`image_id`,`category_id`)

Where one of my images (image_id=1) has two categories (Desert [category_id=1] and Winter [category_id=2]). Which I defined in tbl_image_categories as 1,1 and 1,2.

I also have a few other images that I defined as Desert images [category_id=1].

How would I go about getting which images should be loaded based on the Desert Category?

I tried:

```
SELECT tbl_images.image_url
FROM tbl_images,
tbl_image_categories,
tbl_categories
WHERE tbl_categories.category_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_images.image_url
FROM tbl_images,
tbl_image_categories,
tbl_categories
WHERE chad_categories.category_id = 1 //category_id=1 for Desert
AND chad_images.image_id = chad_image_categories.image_id
AND chad_image_categories.category_id = chad_categories.category_id
```

Comment: Ahhh SELECT DISTINCT. That worked :) Thanks a bunch. I also realized I pasted it wrong on the bottom, vars a different. I'll go and change that. Thanks again!

Comment: Also note you should filter on category_id=1 and not image_id=1 if you want all imager for Desert category.

Comment: I originally didn't have the 2 AND lines, just the WHERE part. It seems just adding those two lines fixes the problem as well.

Comment: Ah yeah, that's what I meant. category_id=1, I pasted the wrong thing from the text file it looks like :(